# Catching unhandled exception of a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

Does one of you has an idea of how to catch in the main thread of an application an exception thrown in a particular thread ?

For example, I have a very simple thread doing some basic stuff :

```
 try
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Cache.initialize));
            t.Start();
            t.Name = "loading";
            while (t.IsAlive)
            {
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
             }
        }

        catch (PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("L'application ne peut se connecter au serveur, vérifiez votre connexion");
        }
```

the problem is that this catch is useless, because the exception won't be retrieved in the main stack..

```
    public static void initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                ctxMdv = new ClientContext(Configuration.getInstance().UrlMdv);
                ...                
            }

            catch (PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException e) //si le serveur n'est pas démarré
{
                throw ;
            }
```

here everything stops at the "throw" and nothing is handled, even if in the main stack I tried to catch it displaying a message box.
So how could I catch this PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException raised in my thread ?
Would you have some best practice to catch exception from a thread in c# ?

Thank you very much !

PS  : Okay thanks to the answer given by Thorsten Dittmar below, I could make it work like that :
here is the main thread

```
 BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

here is my dowork :

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Cache.initialize(); // the thread job
    }
```

here is mi completed event, that happens even if an exception is raised :

```
 private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!(e.Error == null))

            if (e.Error is WebException)
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("L'application ne peut se connecter au serveur, vérifiez votre connexion");

         this.Dispose();
         Application.Exit();
    }
```

And I'm planning to handle the ProgressChanged delegate to correct the progression bar... ;)
thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one way would be to use `BackgroundWorker` instead of a thread in your situation. You don't need a `try` block there, as errors will be automatically caught and passed to the handler you assign when the worker ends.

EDIT:
You can also use an event of `BackgroundWorker` to report progress to your form, so you can update your progress bar properly ;-)

Comment: okay ! it's working ! thank you very much !
I'll edit my post posting the solution code thanks to you